# Which evaluation methods can I use for image segmentation?

Tags: computer-vision, datasets, image-segmentation

I implemented an image segmentation pipeline and I trained it on the [DICOM dataset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DICOM). I compared the results of the model with manual segmentation to find the accuracy. Is there other methods for evaluation?

Answer (score 2):

See:

> Martin Thoma: [A Survey of Semantic Segmentation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.06541.pdf), Section III

Subsection A is about metrics and B is about datasets.

Metrics include: accuracy, IoU, frequency weighted IoU, F-beta score, speed, ...

Answer (score 1):

The paper referenced by Martin Thoma is the go-to for semantic segmentation. However I will also like to add the Panoptic Segmentation metric as an aggregated method to measure both the detection task and segmentation task of the model.

It is a very well-known and widely used metric since it is the standard metric for COCO dataset (segmentation)

[This is the paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.00868) where the metric is proposed.

And here is the metric:

[image]